# The distribution of pairwise distance of points sampled uniformly sampled from special shapes

Tags: probability, general-topology, geometry, algebraic-topology

Chord length distribution is the distribution of pairwise distances between points uniformly sampled from n-dimensional hypersphere. https://arxiv.org/pdf/1411.5639.pdf shows closed-form expressions of PDF and CDF of this kind of distribution for n-dimensional hypersphere.

I wonder if there are some similar results if we uniformly sample points from a 2-dimensional ring (circle with some thickness), or some interesting shapes in higher dimensions such as torus in 3-dimensional space.

Besides, I am curious whether the shapes of pairwise distance distributions have some relationships with some topological properties such as the homology group, one simulation that I already have is as the following, the points are sampled from rings with different thicknesses, and we draw the frequency histograms of pairwise distances. the homology groups of the last three shapes are the same ($H_{0}=1$, $H_{1}=1$), and likewise, their corresponding distributions have two "peaks". I wonder if there are already some mathematically formalized results related to the pairwise distance distribution and topological or geometrical properties of the sampled space for now.
[image]
Thanks!